# New Group Policy Objects Include Unwanted Settings

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy, groups

It looks like my server admin tools are adding the following unwanted settings to every GPO I touch.

Computer Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Options/Public Key Policies/Trusted Root Certification Authorities

**Allow users to select new root certification authorities (CAs) to trust**: Enabled

**Client computers can trust the following certificate stores:** Third-Party Root Certification Authorities and Enterprise Root Certification Authorities

**To perform certificate-based authentication of users and computers, CAs must meet the following criteria:** Registered in Active Directory only

It's causing weird problems like certain CAs stop being trusted by IE.  What the heck is going on?  I'm using the RSAT 2008 r2/Win 7 on a Win 7 x64 machine.

Answer (score 1):

The setting Computer/Policies/Administrative Templates/System/Internet Communication Management/Restrict Internet communication - Settings was doing this.